# mock gtest compilation error

Tags: googletest

i had crated a class say "GTEST_static_class.h" and created a mock for it MockGTEST_static_class.h, after that i am creating  GTest_static_example.cpp, which call' the mock class MockGTEST_static_class.

the problem is that i am getting the compilation error..

### compilation error

```
/x/opt/pp/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h: In copy constructor âtesting::internal::FunctionMocker<void ()()>::FunctionMocker(const testing::internal::FunctionMocker<void ()()>&)â:
/x/opt/pp/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1656: error: âtesting::internal::FunctionMockerBase<F>::FunctionMockerBase(const testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase<F>&) [with F = void ()()]â is private
/x/opt/pp/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:89: error: within this context
package/web/webscr/MockGTEST_static_class.h: In copy constructor âMockGTEST_static_class::MockGTEST_static_class(const MockGTEST_static_class&)â:
package/web/webscr/MockGTEST_static_class.h:7: note: synthesized method âtesting::internal::FunctionMocker<void ()()>::FunctionMocker(const testing::internal::FunctionMocker<void ()()>&)â first required here
package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.cpp: In member function âvirtual void GTest_static_example_case1_Test::TestBody()â:
package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.cpp:42: note: synthesized method âMockGTEST_static_class::MockGTEST_static_class(const MockGTEST_static_class&)â first required here
distcc[751] ERROR: compile package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.cpp on localhost failed
runtask: /x/opt/pp/bin/distcc /usr/bin/g++ -D __LINUX__ -D _GNU_SOURCE -D XERCES_VERSION_AT_LEAST_27 -D WITH_OPENSSL -O2 -m32 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Werror -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_EQ -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_NE -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_LE -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_LT -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_GE -D GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_ASSERT_GT -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -ftemplate-depth-48 -D GSOAP_PPSB -fpermissive -fno-enforce-eh-specs -Wno-deprecated -feliminate-unused-debug-types -I/x/local/gopc/gimp/code -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/ffxclient-devel-101.0-5531003.i686.rpm-install/include -I/x/paypal/build_uncert/RHEL5.4/infra/101.0.5447330/ifeature/include -I/x/paypal/build_uncert/RHEL5.4/infra/101.0.5447330/infra/include -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/ivr-biz-devel-1.0-4657646.i686.rpm-install/include -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/ivrserv-devel-1.0-4725318.i686.rpm-install/include -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/riskaimcommon-101.0.SNAPSHOT.rpm-install/include -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/sec-engg-devel-legacyBF_int-5077867.i686.rpm-install/include -I/x/local/gopc/scratch/prebuilts/user-devel-101.0-5530926.i686.rpm-install/include -isystem /x/opt/pp -isystem /usr/include/libxml2 -isystem /usr/include/xercesc -isystem /x/home/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/include -isystem /x/opt/ppdb4-4.5.20/include -isystem /x/opt/pp/include -isystem /x/opt/pp/include/mimepp -isystem /x/opt/pp/include/python2.6 -c package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.cpp -o package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.o exited with status 1
make: *** [package/web/webscr/GTest_static_example.o] Error 1
mm: WARNING: make exited with status 2
# Make finished with status 2 in 0.10 minutes (0.10 total)
```

### GTEST_static_class.h

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class GTEST_static_class
{

public:
                 void display()
                {
                        cout<< "inside the GTEST_static_class:: display " <<endl;
                }

};
```

### MockGTEST_static_class.h

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "GTEST_static_class.h"

class MockGTEST_static_class : public GTEST_static_class
{
        public:
                        static GTEST_static_class m_GTEST_static_class;

                        static void set_instance( GTEST_static_class _class)
                        {
                                m_GTEST_static_class = _class;
                        }

                        /*
                        static iGTEST_static_class GTEST_class;
                        static void set_instance( GTEST_static_class _class)
                        {
                                GTEST_class = _class;
                        }
                        */
                        MOCK_METHOD0(display,void(void));

};
```

### GTest_static_example.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MockGTEST_static_class.h"

using namespace std;

class GTest_static_example : public::testing::Test
{
public:
                virtual void SetUp();
                virtual void TearDown();
                void call_display()
                {
                        GTEST_static_class _class = GTEST_static_class();
                        _class.display();
                        cout<<"display called from GTest_static_example"<<endl;
                }

};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
        return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
        //return 1;
}

void GTest_static_example::SetUp()
{

}


void GTest_static_example::TearDown()
{

}

TEST_F(GTest_static_example,case1)
{
                MockGTEST_static_class mock = MockGTEST_static_class();
                MockGTEST_static_class::set_instance(mock);
                //set_instance(mock);
                EXPECT_CALL(mock,display()).Times(1);
                //EXPECT_CALL(GTEST_static_class,display()).Times(1);
                call_display();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which shows the problem?

Comment: basically i want to mock the call "display" inside the call_display.. also i did commented the "static GTEST_static_class m_GTEST_static_class" and set_instance, it is compiling now, and executing. but how can i mock "_class.display()" for the call_display